# How to set a maximum height, response, primeng tree

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have a primeNg containing a primeNg tree.
What I must have is response modal.
I have to have the tree fully expanded.
With the above settings, there are instances that the dialog/tree are longer than the screen.

Is there a way to style the dialog to be responsive with a maximum height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this,

```
<p-tree [value]="Files" (onNodeExpand)="nodeExpand($event)" [style]="{'max-height':'200px','overflow':'auto'}"></p-tree>
```

Comment: Setting the height for a p-tree doesn't work for me even using this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

@reza.. if you want to expand your dialog to maximum height of the screen responsively. Use this,
`style="height:100vh"`